# Multiple simultaneous requests on same session fail

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project. When multiple requests are made using the same session simultaneously, `\Auth::user()` returns `null` on some requests in my service provider.

For example, when a page loads and on the client side using AngularJS, we make 3 simultaneous JSON requests for data after `onload`. 2 of the 3 JSON requests fail because in my service provider, the `\Authorization::user()` returns null.

- In all requests, the session id is always correct, the problem is not the session info not being provided.
- In my middleware, I am calling `\Authorization::user()` which returns the user successfully every time, including all simultaneous requests.
- In my service provider, when calling `\Authorization::user()` with multiple simultaneous requests it fails on some of the requests.

How do I fix my service provider?

**My service provider**

```
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('permissions', function() {

            // we have already checked \Auth::user() in middleware
            // before getting here, this should never fail
            // this fails 2 of 3 times when accessed simultaneously
            // with same session

            $u = \Auth::user();
            if (empty($u)) {
                \Log::error(__METHOD__, ['singleton' => 'permissions', 'error' => 'invalid_user']);
                return new PermissionCache(0);
            }
            return new PermissionCache($u->employeeId);
        });
    }
}
```

**My Middleware Class:**

```
class MyApiMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // this always works for all requests
        
        $u = \Auth::user();
        if (empty($u)) {
            \Log::error(__METHOD__, ['url' => $request->url(), 'session' => $request->session()->getId(), 'error' => 'user_invalid']);
            return \Response::json(ExceptionHelper::CreateToArray('invalidAuthorization'), 500);
        }
        
        // the following fails when it should be good
        // because in MyServiceProvider, sometimes
        // \Auth::user() returns null even though
        // above it worked perfectly, as it should
        
        $p = \App::make('permissions');
        if (!$p->allowSomthing()) {
            \Log::error(__METHOD__, ['url' => $request->url(), 'session' => $request->session()->getId(), 'error' => 'permission_invalid']);
            return \Response::json(ExceptionHelper::CreateToArray('invalidAuthorization'), 500);
        }
        
    }
}
```

**My Middleware Declaration:**

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
//        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'public' => [
//        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'session' => [
//        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            MySessionMiddleware::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
//        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            MyApiMiddleware::class,
        ],
    ];

}
```

**Session Config, default values used:**

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => FALSE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', NULL),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', NULL),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', NULL),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
    'http_only' => TRUE,
    'same_site' => 'lax',
];
```

Comment: Are CSRF tokens involved? Perhaps that could be the issue (subsequent requests invalidating previous tokens)

Comment: No, it is not CSRF.  The error is past that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was I was try to get the session/auth value in my controller::__construct. Session info in the request when the controller is initialized has not been loaded yet. My unit tests didn't catch this because this info was mocked and my project is being upgraded from laravel 4.2 which this worked in.